# Joomla to Drupal module - migrating issues

Tags: 7, migrations

Notes: Drupal 7.x. Joomla to Drupal module version 1.0 ALPHA3

I was playing with the Joomla to Drupal module, which is currently in alpha. I had imported some 100 content items from a Joomla install using this tool. However, making changes to some of the content was producing errors, so I decided to start fresh; I deleted all of the imported content.

I then attempted to redo the import, however, it threw additional database entry related errors stating that it was unable to overwrite tables.

I decided to start anew by disabling and then removing the module and its related tables all together; logged into mysql and removed tables `joomla_categories` `joomla_content` `joomla_sections` and `joomla_users` as well as the joomla directory under `../sites/all/modules`.

I proceeded to reinstall the module, and went to configure it; all of the settings were intact i.e. database name, password, etc. from the previous install (caching?).

I go to perform the import, and a database error shows up stating that the `joomla_users` table does not exist. I log back into mysql and notice that the module did not recreate the joomla_ database tables.

Isn't the module responsible for creating these tables? Can anyone see what I may have done wrong in my process? If the module doesn't create the tables, what does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it, the module was not uninstalled correctly. You should first disable the module, then when the modules page reloads, uninstall it.  During the uninstall process is when [hook_uninstall()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_uninstall/7) is run and the database tables and any saved variables (from the variable table) should be deleted.

If you didn't uninstall the module correctly, Drupal never performed these actions, and therefore still believed the module was installed.  Since it believed the module was already installed, the database tables would not be created.

For more information regarding uninstalling modules see the article: [Uninstalling Modules](http://drupal.org/node/250783)

Comment: I disabled the module first before attempting to delete the tables/files. I'm not sure if maybe it's because the module is an Alpha release, but there is no uninstall feature for it. I navigate to modules and click on the uninstall tab, and the module does not exist on the list. I checked the module and it does include the uninstall hook, but it doesn't seem to be implemented.

Comment: I just installed and uninstalled Joomla to Drupal 7.x-1.0-alpha3 and it added/removed the database tables fine. Perhaps take a look at the article I mentioned above for more on uninstalling modules

Comment: I was able to fix my database errors by throwing up another test drupal install and installing the module, then backup/restore a dump of the joomla_ tables to my site. After the reinstall, I noticed that the option to uninstall was there. Maybe something got fudged the first time and the uninstall wasn't available for me. But it's there now =/. Thanks for the assistance.